# Not able to use 'request' in django MultiTableMixin class

Tags: django, python-3.5, django-tables2

Am using django MultiTableMixin to list multiple tables in a page. I want to check user permissions from request and list table data, but am not able to get request in my class 'PersonTablesView'.

The following is the sample code I got from a tutorial.

```
from django_tables2 import MultiTableMixin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
class PersonTablesView(MultiTableMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'multiTable.html'
    tables = [
        PersonTable(qs),
        PersonTable(qs, exclude=('country', ))
    ]

    table_pagination = {
        'per_page': 10
    }
```

please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What permissions would you like to check? Did you have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views

Comment: On every Django class based views, request are accessible through self.request